# In test classes using main classes in other modules in a multi-module maven project

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a multi-module Maven project. structure look like this:

```
 Parent
|-- Module A
        |-- src/test
            |-- TestA
|-- Module B
        |-- src/main
            |-- B
```

in Module A, I have  test class TestA that use B class declared in module B ( src/main/B).
How can I share the B class to be recognized in TestA?
Remark: I need to share the main Classes in B Module (not the test classes)
ModuleB is spring boot module

Comment: Just add a Maven test dependency in Module A to Module B? Am I missing something?

Comment: it doesnt' work. to forget to mention that ModuleB is spring boot module

Comment: Can you explain for what purpose because you already wrote that ModuleB is a spring boot module ...why not putting your tests into ModuleB ? ` src/test/java/<packageName>/...`?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference if B is a spring boot module or not. Please share your code (pom files) and explain what you have tried. Specifically, have you tried to add a test dependency and if it didn't work what error did you get?